# Form validation with Struts 2 + Dojo framework

Tags: dojo, struts2, struts, validation, struts-validation

I'm new on Dojo, and I'm trying to validate a form (like the last one of this example : http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/validation/), using Struts2 tags, but I can't.
With a "classic" HTML form (tags ,  ....) everything is fine, but with Struts 2 tags (), the "required" validation don't work ...

Here is my code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require('dojox.validate');
        dojo.require('dojox.validate.us');
        dojo.require('dojox.validate.web');

        /* basic dijit classes */
        dojo.require('dijit.form.CheckBox');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.Textarea');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.FilteringSelect');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.TextBox');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.ValidationTextBox');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.DateTextBox');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.TimeTextBox');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.Button');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.RadioButton');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.Form');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.DateTextBox');

        /* basic dojox classes */
        dojo.require('dojox.form.BusyButton');
        dojo.require('dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect');
    </script>

<s:form dojoType="dijit.form.Form" method="post" id="toto" 
 theme="simple">
      <script type="dojo/method" event="onSubmit">
            if(this.validate()) {
               return confirm('Form is valid, press OK to submit');
            } else {
               alert('Formulaire invalide');
             return false;
            }
return true;
            </script>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><strong>First Name*: </strong></td>
                    <td>
                        <s:textfield
                            name="email"
                            id="email"
                            placeholder="Your email" 
                            dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" 
                            required="true"
                            missingMessage="Obligatoire !" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

                <s:submit
                    value="Submit Form" 
                    label="Submit Form"
                    id="submitButton" 
                    dojoType="dijit.form.Button"/>
            </s:form>
```

How can I check that my fields are not empty with struts tags please ?
Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check to make sure that what you're rendering is what Dojo expects. I don't know how the current Dojo validation works, but:

The "required" attribute is an attribute of `<s:textfield>`, it's likely not being rendered, thus not available to Dojo--if that's what Dojo uses to determine if a field is required.

Comment: Hi, Dojo is waiting for "required" attribute, but like you said, this one is not rendered by the "s:textfield" tag, so Dojo can't find him and does not know that the field is required. This is my question : how can I do ?

Comment: I found my solution. Just have to put data-dojo-props="required : true" as <s:textfield /> attribute

Comment: @Vince So, you're welcome. Normally a helpful answer or a solution gets [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), or at least an upvote.

Comment: Don't be offended, but your post doesn't help me. I knew about the "required" attribute of <s:textfield> tag, but the solution was to put it into "data-dojo-props" attribute. But I "accept" your solution because you were the only on answering me (I can't upvote because I don't get 15 reputation) . Thank you about that

Comment: @Vince Then don't accept it-answer your own question, and accept that. (Although if you knew about the required property seems like *why* it wasn't working would be obvious?)